# How to make use of madvise and associated macros?

Tags: c, gcc

When I compile using `gcc --std=c99 -g -Wall ...` I get this:

```
warning: implicit declaration of function ‘madvise’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
...
error: ‘MADV_DONTNEED’ undeclared
...
```

So I used this: `` `gcc -print-prog-name=cpp` -v `` to find where my compiler is looking for headers and found that there is only header for `sys/mman.h` so I looked at the files source and it shows this:

```
#ifdef __USE_BSD
/* Advise the system about particular usage patterns the program follows
   for the region starting at ADDR and extending LEN bytes.  */
extern int madvise (void *__addr, size_t __len, int __advice) __THROW;
#endif
```

I did some research into why `__USE_BSD` wouldn't be defined but didn't find much. What I did find is that `features.h` can be used to define it. So I tried putting this at the top of my code:

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE 1
#include <features.h>
```

This seems to work but I've never done this sort of thing before. am I going about this the right way? I'm just concerned that my methodology is a bit hacky...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I happened across a reference to `feature_test_macros(7)` which suggests defining as I have in my question, or (as I have opted to do) use the -D flag to define the macros using the compiler. I chose this option so that the macros I need defined will be defined for across multiple source files.